# Regexp that ignore words within a block

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a way for regexp to only match if the word is not surround by {c} text {/c} block, and found a way

```
/(?![^{]*.*})(.+?)(?![^{]*.*})/g
```

but it ignores anything surround by two {} ({} text{} is ignored) which isn't what i want.
The regexp is for my chat app which is written in node js.
The point is that i want other regexp to not parse anything in side {c} {/c} block, even the other {c} {/c} block, something like

> ```
> {c} 
>    {c} text {/c} this is how you show codes 
> {/c}
> ```

becomes

> ```
> <pre> 
>    {c} text {/c} this is how you show codes 
> </pre>
> ```

EDIT: This is what i am using right now.

```
var from = [
/(?![^{]*.*})`(.+?)`(?![^{]*.*})/g, /*bold `text`*/
/(?![^{]*.*})''(.+?)''(?![^{]*.*})/g, /*italics ''text''*/
/(?![^{]*.*})~~(.+?)~~(?![^{]*.*})/g, /*strikethrough ~text~*/
/(?![^{]*.*})@@(.+?)@@(?![^{]*.*})/g, /*code @@text@@*/
/{q}\s*(.+?)\s*{\/q}/g, /*quote {q}text{/q}*/
/{c}\s*(.+?)\s*{\/c}/g, /*preview {c}text{/c}*/
];

var to = [
    "<strong>$1</strong>",
    "<em>$1</em>",
    "<span style='text-decoration:line-through'>$1</span>",
    "<code>$1</code>",
    "<blockquote>$1</blockquote><br />",
    "<pre class=\"code\">$1</pre><br />",
];
```

Comment: Regexp is not well-suited for handling this type of nested construct.

Comment: Can you tell me other possible solutions? Regexp is the only thing I know when doing this kind of work.

Comment: we can do with pure javascript also

Answer (score 1):

The below regular expression will do the same job. It'll mathes the entire string wrapped in between `{c}` and `{/c}`.

```
/{c}(.*){\/c}/g
```

With pure **Javascript:**

```js
var str = "{c} {c} text {/c} this codes {/c}";

var word1 = "{c}", word2 = "{/c}"; // words to be removed
var newWord1 = "<PRE>", newWord2 = "</PRE>"; // words need to be replaced

var fIndex = str.indexOf(word1); // getting first occurance of word1
str = str.replace(str.substring(0, word1.length), newWord1); // replacing it with newWord1

var lIndex = str.lastIndexOf(word2); // getting index of last occurance of word2
str = str.substring(0, lIndex) + newWord2 + str.substring(lIndex+word2.length, str.length); // and replacing it with newWord2

console.log(str);
```

Comment: This works if {c} block is inside another {c} block, but does not work if another block like {c} {q} {/q} {/c}

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you. can you comment example input and output for the above case?

Comment: See my edited question. I use {q} to parse blockquote, {c} to parse preview. When I type, {c}{q}{/q}{/c}, i get <pre><block></block></pre>, but i want it to be <pre>{q} {/q}</pre>

Comment: This will eat up everything between the first `{c}` and the last `{/c}`, which is probably not what you want if there are multiple top-level `{c}` blocks.

Comment: The javascript one will run incorrectly if i have multiple different {c} blocks. {c}abc{/c} {c}def{/c} for example.

Comment: Sorry, i didn't consider that case. I'll update my answer